# Google Vision API showing service unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, google-cloud-speech

I am getting **service unavailable** error while trying to use [vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/). It used to work previously, but suddenly started showing error 503.

```
"ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."\n}')"
```

Any help how to get rid of this?

Comment: Try again with new token

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your service account/token. Here is some info on token expiration: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration